# Git - origin/master diverged - throwing away abandoned commit

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I've been doing my project while at some point I discovered that one thing stopped working. I needed to look up the state of my code when it was working correctly, so I've decided to use git checkout (because I wanted to check-something-out). And so I've done

```
git checkout SHA
```

Then I've done two new commits hoping it will create new HEAD. It did not, instead I got:

```
    On branch master
    Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
    and have 2 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
      (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
    nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I've tried rebasing and merging but all it does is overwriting my HEAD with changes from the "abandoned" commit.

All I would like to do is to make my newly created commits the true undiverged HEAD. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe `git rebase` would work here and my guess is you're not using it correctly.  Could you please show us the command?  Show us the command for merge too, since I believe you could get that working too.

Comment: So to clarify - you're checking out a commit from a while ago and you want to make changes from this point and then replace the old history with your new commits?

Comment: Did you pushed the change to master before you checked out SHA?

Answer (score 0):

When you checkout to a `specific commit` and `add` a new commit, you need to checkout a new branch & push to remote. After merging the `new-branch` with `master` you will get the commit in `master` branch.

```
$ git checkout <commit-sha>

# add a commit
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'message'

# checkout a new branch (say, feature)
$ git checkout -b feature

# sync with remote/master & push to remote/feature
$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin HEAD            # push to remote/feature

# merge 'feature' branch with master and push to remote/master
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin feature         # merge 'feature' branch with 'master'
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: i believe this wont work as his message appears to be saying that master has since moved on since the merge-base/merge point.

Comment: ah, ignore the previous comment, yeah after he pushes the feature branch he'll need to merge it into master, which I assume you implied.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer. Push `feature` then `merge` with local/master, push to remote/master.

Answer (score 0):

At this point you can run

```
git checkout -b branchname
```

to create a branch at the current commit and set `HEAD` to it.

If `branchname` is already in use, `-B` will overwrite it.

Answer (score -1):

Make a branch off of the commits. Then merge that branch into your old branch.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "All I would like to do is to make my newly created commits the true undiverged HEAD. Is it possible?".
Yes, this would have helped stop the asker getting in this position in the first place, but doesn't help him at all now. Maybe try updating your answer to provide an actual answer as well as this useful advice?

Comment: @MatthewHallatt It's rather simple. Just create new branch from the new "head" and then merge that branch. This is basic git stuff once the new branch is created